# Updating matrix values updates entire row

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix

I have the following code:

```
def matrixReshape(mat, r, c):
    if len(mat)*len(mat[0]) != r*c:
        return mat

    nums = []
    for row in range(len(mat)):
        for col in range(len(mat[0])):
            nums.append(mat[row][col])

    res = [[0]*c]*r
    for x in range(r):
        for y in range(c):
            res[x][y] = nums.pop(0)

    return res

mat = [[1,2],[3,4]]

print(matrixReshape(mat, 4, 1))
```

Which results in the output:

```
[[4], [4], [4], [4]]
```

But I want it to output:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

I'm confused why the entire column gets updated. When I print `x` and `y` in the 2nd `for` loops I get: `0,0 1,0 2,0 3,0` as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're initializing the `res` variable like this:

```
        res = [[0]*c]*r
```

This makes every element in the array reference the same value.
Use a list comprehension to initialize the list instead, which will copy all the elements. This is the pythonic way to initialize lists.

```
res = [[0 for _ in range(c)] for _ in range(r)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the line.

```
res = [[0]*c]*r
```

When multiplying `[0]` with r and c, array `[0]` is replicated. So changing any of its instances will change a value for all.

Try the following line instead.

```
res = [[0 for i in range(c)] for j in range(r)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple list comprehension

```
[[col] for row in mat for col in row]
```